# Showing Hat matrix equal specific values

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, regression

Consider a one way layout model $y_{ij}$ = $\mu_i + e_{ij}$ (1 $\leq$ i $\leq$ a, 1 $\leq$ j $\leq$ $n_i$) where a = 3 and $n_1$ = 2, $n_2$ = 3, $n_3$ = 4. Show that the hat matrix for this design equals:

$ H = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 &  1/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 &  1/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 &  1/4 & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/4 &  1/4 & 1/4 \end{array} \right|. $

I am stuck as I am unable to find the inverse of X'X:

$ X'X = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
9 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
2 & 2 & 0 & 0  \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
4 & 0 & 0 & 4  \\
\end{array} \right|. $

I believe that I need to put some sort of constraint on the X'X matrix, but I'm not sure how to do this.